# Vaadin Elements get input value of Paper-Input

Tags: javascript, java, polymer, vaadin

I've incorporated the [Elements add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/elements-add-on) for Vaadin into my project and I've got a simple login setup that has two input fields and a button.  However, I'm running into a roadblock in how to get the value of the input fields when a user clicks the submit button.

My eventlistener on submit is simple:

```
button.addEventListener("click", args -> submitLogin());
```

where the submitLogin() attempts to get the values and pass them to a controller.

```
controller.submit(username.getValue(), password.getValue());
```

However, no method I have tried actually returns a non-null value.  Any ideas?

**Code for paper-input interface:**

```
@Tag("paper-input")
@Import("VAADIN/bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html")
public interface PaperInput extends Element {

public static PaperInput create(String caption) {
    PaperInput input = create();
    input.setLabel(caption);
    return input;
}

public static PaperInput create() {
    return Elements.create(PaperInput.class);
}
}
```

which references the paper-input html [here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-input/blob/master/paper-input.html)

and is used simply by calling create(), like so:

```
PaperInput usernameInput = PaperInput.create();
```

The PaperButton is created identically but references the paper-button in @iimport and @Tag.

Comment: please add at least the code, how you build your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client side must bind the value to the `change`. There are two examples in the [Lab](https://vaadin.com/labs-elements):

In case you create your element directly:

```
input.bindAttribute("value", "change")
```

Or with the interface approach (which you seem to use):

```
public void setValue(String value)

@UpdatedBy("change")
public String getValue()
```

Disclainer: I only tried it with a Groovy DSL around elements.